# process a sequence in a java.util.stream manner in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, java-stream

Does someone know how I would write a sequence processing in a java stream API manner in Python ? The idea is to write the operations in the order they will happen:

```
myList.stream()
    .filter(condition)
    .map(action1)
    .map(action2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now in python I could do

```
[action2(action1(item)) for item in my_list if condition(item)]
```

But that is the opposite order.

How could I have something in the correct order ? Obviously I could use variables but then I would have to find a name for each partial result.

Comment: In a Python world view, having to find names for the intermediate results is a feature, not a bug. Those names will be most helpful to a human reader in figuring out what the code is intended to achieve.

Comment: Mh... no, it is not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a library that already does exactly what you are looking for, i.e. lazy evaluation and the order of operations is the same with how it's written, as well as many more other good stuff like multiprocess or multithreading Map/Reduce.
It's named [`pyxtension`](https://github.com/asuiu/pyxtension), it's prod ready, covered by unit-tests and maintained on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pyxtension/), and it's released under MIT license - so you can use it for free in any commercial project.
Your code would be rewritten in this form:

```
from pyxtension.streams import stream

stream(myList)
    .filter(condition)
    .map(action1)
    .map(action2)
    .toList()
```

and

```
stream(myList)
    .filter(condition)
    .mpmap(action1)   # this is for multi-processing map
    .fastmap(action2) # this is multi-threaded map
    .toList()
```

Note that the last statement `toList()` does exact what you expect - it collects data as it would happen in a Spark RDD.

Comment: Attention. This project is not widely used and has a GPL license; which means you must not use it in many cases.

Comment: you mistyped "pyxtension.strams". It should be "pyxtension.streams"

Comment: Thank you @miwe for observation about license, it was changed to MIT license, so now it can be used in any case.

Comment: Great find asu! I'll be googling this shortly, but would be interested in identifying anything that could act as a java to `pxtension` bridge, such that I could write/define workflows in python using `pxtension` but locate and iterate over streams from various data sources using java components for io.

Comment: @ThomasKimber - sure, you just use Jython for it. pyxtension is written in pure-python, so it's expected to work on Jython. The disadvantage is that the latest version of Jython is 2.7.3, so it doesn't support 3.x syntax, but it's scales easier as it's not affected by GIL

Answer (score 4):

You could write this yourself:

```
from collections import UserList


class JavaLike(UserList):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.iter = None

    def stream(self):
        self.iter = None

        return self

    def filter(self, function):
        self.iter = filter(function, self if self.iter is None else self.iter)

        return self

    def map(self, function):
        self.iter = map(function, self if self.iter is None else self.iter)

        return self

    def collect(self, collection_class=None):
        if collection_class is None:
            if self.iter is not None:
                ret = JavaLike(self.iter)
                self.iter = None

                return ret

            return JavaLike(self)

        return collection_class(self if self.iter is None else self.iter)
```

Then a similar syntax is possible:

```
>>> JavaLike(range(10)).stream().filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0).map(str).collect(tuple)
('0', '2', '4', '6', '8')
```

Comment: I must say I hoped something built in existed but that is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two modules on PyPI: [lazy-streams](https://pypi.org/project/lazy-streams/)  and [pystreams](https://pypi.org/project/pystreams/)

Comment: I may be picky but I avoid to use anything that isn't mature, except if I'm desperate. Meanwhile I found https://pypi.org/project/Rx/ which seems answer my needs. I didn't test it yet though.

Comment: For does that are allergic to 0.x.x releases I can announce that lazy-streams reached 1.0.0 august 2022. I'm not a contributor.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention the [`streamable`](https://github.com/ebonnal/streamable) module I wrote (would love to get feedback!):

Your example would look like:

```py
from typing import List
from streamable import Stream

class Item: ...

def condition(item: Item) -> bool: ...

def action1(item: Item) -> Item: ...

def action2(item: Item) -> Item: ...

my_list: List[Item] = ...

# lazy operations
stream: Stream[Item] = (
    Stream(lambda: my_list)
    .filter(condition)
    .map(action1)
    .map(action2)
)

# collect
list(stream)
```

- this is a ***typed*** module with 100% code coverage and no dependency
- the `Stream[T]` class extends `Iterable[T]`
- a stream is ***immutable***
- operations are ***lazily evaluated*** and cover concurrency, grouping/flattening, exceptions catching, rate limiting, iteration progress logging, ...

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't reversed() do the trick?

> [action2(action1(item)) for item in reversed(my_list) if
> condition(item)]

Comment: No. The order of the elements of the list has nothing to do with the order of the operations executed on the list.